# Linking text to map using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to know if it is possible to link a text to a leaflet map.
I would like to highlight a country in my map when the mouse is hover a word in my text.
My map is created with leaflet library.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

(This was what you asked, but probably not the answer you are looking for. Please put some more effort into phrasing your question, give us an idea of what you've tried so far and other relevant information.)

Answer (score 1):

I just gave it  a quick try and yes it works:

You can assign an id to every feature:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    // just add this line to your onEachFeature-Function: 

    layer._polygonId = feature.id;  // assigning ID to each feature

}
```

I wrote two functions for the mouse-enter and mouse-leave event:
In the hoverstart-function you can use the assigned ID's to choose the feature you want to highlight:

```
var highlighted_feature; // global variable to be used for both functions

    function hoverstart() 
{

    var selectedId = 30; // test-ID for State Montana

    geojson.eachLayer(
        function(layer) {
            if (layer._polygonId == selectedId) {
                highlighted_feature = layer;
                highlighted_feature.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    fillColor: 'red',
                    dashArray: '',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });
            }
        });

}


function hoverstop(e) 
{
    if (highlighted_feature) 
    {
        geojson.resetStyle(highlighted_feature);
    }

}
```

HTML-Part:

Assign an id for your hover-text in order to be able to bind the hover-event-listener a bit later:

```
<span id="montana">Montana</span>
```

And last but not least bind the event-listener for the hover-event to your text:

```
$("#montana").hover( hoverstart, hoverstop );
```

Here is the jsfiddle I set up for this test:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/pc4coem4/

Comment: Hi Josaphine.Could you post your error messages from your console / developer tools? The Id of a feature you can get if you use the following in your onEachFeature-function:
    if(feature.properties.name=='Montana')
    {console.log(feature.id);
}

Comment: I guess you have not included jquery in your app:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: wich error messages do you get?

Comment: if you analyze your javascript code with http://www.jslint.com/ you will find some errors. you can try to fix them or set up a jsfiddle so it's possible to live debug your code ;)